# JPA: Create new join-table within a class

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I've been struggeling with this for some time now and wasn't able to find any useful information in the internet so far.

I am currently working on a project that can be used as administration tool for a pizza-delivery-company (university).

I have a class `Employee`, which holds up an `ArrayList` of `Worktime`-instances. The `Worktime`-class should represent one day of work, with the possibility to start working and pausing several times. I now am struggeling to map this class with JPA. What i would wish for, is a table that holds in start-time,end-time,pause-time and endpause-time, referring to the `worktime` table with `worktimeId`. I tried doing that by just creating a `@JoinTable` where all these belong. How do I make it clear, that these elements are connected to each other? Thanks a lot for taking your time, if anything is unclear, I'm sure I can help out with that.

Definition of `Employee` class vars:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="job")
public class Employee extends Person {
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="job")
    private String job;
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private int employeeID;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ArrayList<Worktime> workedHours = new ArrayList<>();}
```

Definition of `Worktime` class vars:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="worktime")
public class Worktime {
    @Id
    @Column(name="worktime_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int worktimeId;
    @Column(name="date")
    private Date date;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
    private ArrayList<Date> startTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
    private ArrayList<Date> endTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
    private ArrayList<Date> startPauseTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
    private ArrayList<Date> endPauseTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    private Employee employee;}
```

Comment: clearly you cant use a join table to represent 4 different relations ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, just only one *one-to-many* with *WORK-TIMES* should be enough.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
private ArrayList<Date> workTimes = new ArrayList<>();
```

So, for get all  *startTimes*, use

```
@Transient
private ArrayList<Date> startTimes = new ArrayList<>();
//Remove all other annotations

@Transient
public List<Date> getStartTimes () {
    return workTimes.map(workTime -> workTime.getStartTime()).collect(Collection::toList);
}
```